# Why doesn't Mongoose save records as script executes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'll try to be as terse as possible - Mongoose doesn't seem to save records until the entire script ends, even when the save() portion is called asynchronously:

```
var reallyBigData = require('./data.json');

var importData = function(data) {
  var newObj = new Obj; // Mongoose Object
  newObj.x = data.x;
  newObj.save();
};

this.on('importData', importData);

for(var i in reallyBigData) {
  this.emit('importData', reallyBigData[i]);
};
```

This is a gross simplification, but you get the idea. As I run the script and query Mongo, I don't see any records as the script is running. If I limit the number to say, 30, and import those it finishes fast and I see the records afterwards.

Why isn't Mongoose saving each record as the script is executing?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `x.save()` (or `newObj.save()`) is asynchronous and you don't have anything waiting for it to finish other than Node itself.

Being asynchronous, it only *starts* the task of updating the collection in MongoDB and exits immediately after. It won't actually be "*done*" until later, when an optional callback would be called:

```
x.save(function (err, instance) {
    // at this point, it either erred or saved
});
```

Though, it is possible for the `x.save()` to finish nearly instantly. The lower number of records finishing in time to be seen means you have a race condition -- which will finish first: the queries to MongoDB or Node/V8 executing the block of code?

And, using an `EventEmitter`, at least how you have it sampled here, isn't enough to make your loop asynchronous since you're still `emit`ing events synchronously and `emit()` will loop through any handlers synchronously.

However, there are numerous "*control flow*" libraries available that can help. These include implementations of [promises](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/promises), [futures](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/futures), and iterators like [`async`](https://npmjs.org/package/async):

```
var reallyBigData = require('./data.json');

async.each(Object.keys(reallyBigData),
    function (key, callback) {
        new Obj({ x: reallyBigData[key] }).save(callback);
    },

    function (err, results) {
        // called with an `err` or an `Array` of `results` (saved `Obj`s)
    }
);
```

Comment: It's interesting, I worked around the issue by throwing away Mongoose and just using the native driver. I'm wondering if Mongoose does some sort of query caching. I'll experiment around with it more, but it seemed that Mongoose didn't process *any* of the insert requests until after the big loop finished.

Comment: @James Yes, Mongoose does queue queries so that you can *call* them synchronously and have them run asynchrounously. This is one possible solution to "*callback hell*." Also, the native driver is still asynchronous and you should still be using callbacks with `insert()` and an asynchronous iterator.

Answer (score 0):

First off I think you have a nasty error here:

```
var importData = function(data) {
  var newObj = new Obj; // Mongoose Object
  Obj.x = data.x;
  x.save();
};
```

Which should most likely read as:

```
var importData = function(data) {
  var newObj = new Obj; // Mongoose Object
  newObj.x = data.x;
  newObj.save();
};
```

Since it looks like you are trying to operate on your schema and not on the model that you "newed" out of the schema.  Does that make sense?  Or perhaps that is how you have it and you just miss typed?  As is I don't see how you will be getting the expected results from the code that you have in place, regardless of how it is executing to the database.  Perhaps as you have it now it is struggling to detect that the model has changed values, and or it is failing your validation.

Comment: You're right. That was a typo in my question, not in the code. Thanks though.